# Chess in ASP.NET MVC (how to implement M-V-C here)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chess

I just started learning ASP.NET. I have a project at uni - chess (/w playing algorithm, alpha-beta pruning). I decided to implement it in ASP.NET to learn.

And here is my question: what should the model do, and what should the controller do? The view I guess will be just a template displaying the chess pieces and some info.

I saw one guy's app where he put almost all logic into Controller.
Shouldn't game logic go to the Model? I believe that the app runs like:

- detect user action (which field, which piece, to where)
- check if the move is correct (needs complete board
  move info)
- if not, signal that for the user to move again
- if it's correct, process the move and perform the algorithm (computer moves.
  Requires complete board info)
- now it's player's turn again.

So... how would you go about implementing a game of chess in ASP.NET MVC 4/4.5?

Comment: Dunno who downvoted, seems a rather nice question about architectural patterns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @usr suggested, the reason behind MVC is to separate the presentation layer from the business logic layer (in order to improve testability, maintainability, etc.).

In your case (as in all software projects) it really depends on the time and effort you want to put into your solution.

If you want to create something quickly or prototype an idea, then go ahead and put all the logic into the Controllers, you will be quick and prove that your code works, at least.

When the project grows or require maintenance, you will realise that this approach causes more pain than it gives benefits: the code is scattered and the logic is sparse. 
The next step then, requiring a little more effort, is to distil or refactor the knowledge from the Controllers into a set of classes (the domain model) responsible for the game of chess in general.

This way you achieve one important goal: enclosing the whole logic of your project into a manageable, maintainable, and reusable library, maybe surrounded by intention-revealing interfaces which specify the API available to the main project.

This main project can then be a desktop app, a mobile app, a MVC app, whatever you think of it: a thin client around a fully functional and robust core.

You will have to face some decision in this design: for example the classes in the core will generally be different from the models in the MVC app (which tend to be POCO objects in general, although they don't have to); so you will have to decide if you want to go for an adaptor that can map between the two or go for the simpler solution of using the classes in the core as Models in your MVC.

Another problem will probably be the decision on how to manage persistence (saving to the DB).

A thing to not forget, absolutely, is a nice set of tests around your core API: they will define and document its behaviour and will prove an invaluable help during refactoring.

Comment: +1 particularly for the "one important goal":  agree, this is the most important part for me - have a core library that has absolutely no dependencies on anything MVC related, and can be reused in other clients.  Of course, as noted, the size of the project dictates how much this is a concern, but it's a solid principle to follow on pretty much all projects.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your answer is clear and very informative.
I think I'll try to encapsulate chess logic/algorithm in a class, and use that class within a Model...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing `view model` and `business model`. The view model just contains data to be presented (or to be accepted as input). It usually does not contain any logic. Both forms can coexist. Most of the time they are represented as distinct sets of .NET classes, potentially even in a different namespace or assembly.

The business model can do whatever it wants. You can model the board, the pieces etc. there. Your chess engine can operate on the business model. All of this has no relation to the presentation layer at all.

In a database driven application the business model might well be the entity classes that you use with your ORM.

When you want to present you construct a view model from the business model.

Answer (score 1):

The Model define the data structures used within your app.
The Views define how the data is visually rendered.
The Controller governs all logic and user-interaction handling.

The majority of the app logic should go into your Controller classes.

Anything to do with rendering the UI should go into your views. In your case, using ASP.NET MVC, your Views should define an HTML page layout & structure and the code necessary to insert values from your model objects into the correct HTML elements and attributes.

Data storage & retrieval operations should go into your Model, as should any model transformations, manipulation, etc.